# Can I filter data based on an intersection (and) in crossfilter/dc.js?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have the following example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/bp5eavxy/ and am curious if I can select pie slices TP-0 and TP-2 to mean find the patients that have both timepoint 0 and timepoint 2, not 0 or 2.

A sample of the dataset is shown below:

```
    let data = [
        {patientId: 101, site: "AAA", timepoints: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24]},
        {patientId: 102, site: "AAA", timepoints: [0, 2, 4, 6]},
        {patientId: 103, site: "AAA", timepoints: [8, 12, 18, 24]},
        {patientId: 104, site: "AAA", timepoints: [0, 4, 8, 18]},
        {patientId: 105, site: "AAA", timepoints: [2, 6, 12, 24]},
        {patientId: 501, site: "BBB", timepoints: [0]},
        {patientId: 502, site: "BBB", timepoints: [2]},
        {patientId: 503, site: "BBB", timepoints: [4]},
        {patientId: 504, site: "BBB", timepoints: [6]},
        {patientId: 505, site: "BBB", timepoints: [8]},
        {patientId: 506, site: "BBB", timepoints: [12]},
        {patientId: 507, site: "BBB", timepoints: [18]},
        {patientId: 508, site: "BBB", timepoints: [24]}
    ];
```

I would like the resulting intersection filter to produce "AAA" (2), "BBB" (0) since there are two patients at site AAA (101 and 102) that have timepoints 0 **AND** 2 and no patients at site BBB that meet the intersection filter criteria.

Obviously the resulting dataset returns "AAA" (4), "BBB" (2) since there are four patients at site AAA (101, 102, 104, and 105) that have timepoints 0 **OR** 2 and two patients at site BB that meet the union filter criteria.

If it is not possible via crossfilter then I assume I need to capture some event on the tpPie chart and perform my own filtering and then re-populate crossfilter with the new data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I think you have to override the `filterHandler` to provide a `dimension.filterFunction` that checks that the object matches all the filters instead of any of the filters: http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.baseMixin.html#filterHandler__anchor

Comment: While working through the test case I thought about that. Looking at the API for crossfilter I did see: dimension.filterFunction(function) and the API for dc.js I did see: filterHandler( [filterHandler]).  So I decided to first try and tackle this from the crossfilter side and not involve dc.js.  So with the current dataset, siteDimension, siteGroup, tpDimension and tpGroup how could I filter the tpDimension with an intersection to (0 & 2)?

Comment: Hmmm, actually, I guess you can't do this with array dimensions. You'd have to define another dimension and apply your filter on that one within the `filterHandler`. Here's an updates JSFiddle with the Crossfilter-only part of the example: https://jsfiddle.net/b4dq1rea/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @EthanJewett for the comments and crossfilter example in the above comments.  I have been search for this off and on for many months and finally decided to concentrate exclusive to find the answer.  @Gordon you might also be interested in this example.

I have been able to put together a final dc.js and crossfilter [example](https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/bp5eavxy/7/) where you can choose to filter the timepoints based on an intersection (**and**) or a union (**or**).

If you select TP-6 and TP-8 and switch between **or** / **and** you can see it work.  The **and** option is saying that I am looking for patients that have timepoints at 6 and 8.

I have added an additional field "Gender" and another site "CCC" to the dataset.

Based on Ethan's guidance the key part that I was missing was defining an additional dimension that will be filtered when the timepoint pie chart is begin filtered as an intersection (**and**).

The timepoint pie chart dimension is defined below.  The true argument lets the dimension know that the data is an array:

```
let tpDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.timepoints;}, true);
```

The extra dimension is also defined as above except we do not break out the array,  thus the true argument is not passed.  This dimension is only used in the timepoint pie chart filterHandler.

```
let tp2Dimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {return d.timepoints;});
```

The timepoint pie chart filter handler is overridden to use the extra dimension if the user has selected the **and** option.

```
tpPie.filterHandler(function (dimension, filters) {
    if (filters.length === 0) {
       // the empty case (no filtering)
       dimension.filter(null);
    } else if (filters.length === 1 && !filters[0].isFiltered) {
       // single value and not a function-based filter
       dimension.filterExact(filters[0]);
    } else if (filters.length === 1 && filters[0].filterType === 'RangedFilter') {
       // single range-based filter
       dimension.filterRange(filters[0]);
    } else {
       // an array of values, or an array of filter objects
       dimension.filterFunction(function (d) {
           for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                var filter = filters[i];
                if (filter.isFiltered && filter.isFiltered(d)) {
                    return true;
                 } else if (filter <= d && filter >= d) {
                    return true;
                 }
            }
            return false;
        });
     };

   // -------------------------------------------------------------
   // Custom code to handle intersection filtering (AND)
   if (glbTpFilterOption === 'tpAND') {
       tpIntersectFilter(filters);
   }

   return filters;
});
```

The actual code to perform the timepoint intersect filter is:

```
    function tpIntersectFilter(filters) {
        if (filters.length === 1) {
            // Do not perform the intersect test when only 1 filter selected
            tp2Dimension.filterAll();
        } else if (filters.length === 0) {
            // Since nothing is filtered we need to perform an intersect
            // based on all keys.
            tp2Dimension.filter(function (d) {
                uniqueObjs = tpGroup.all();
                for (var i = 0; i < uniqueObjs.length; i++) {
                    if (d.indexOf(uniqueObjs[i].key) == -1) return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        } else {
            tp2Dimension.filter(function (d) {
                // Since we are looking for the intersection, test all 
                // filters, but once there isn't a match get out.
                for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
                    if (d.indexOf(filters[i]) == -1) return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
```

Finally I need to handle when the user is switching between the options:

```
$('#tpFilterOptions a').on('click', function () {
    var sel = $(this).data('title');
    var tog = $(this).data('toggle');
    $('#' + tog).prop('value', sel);

    $('a[data-toggle="' + tog + '"]').not('[data-title="' + sel + '"]').removeClass('active').addClass('notActive');
    $('a[data-toggle="' + tog + '"][data-title="' + sel + '"]').removeClass('notActive').addClass('active');

    glbTpFilterOption = sel;
    if (sel === "tpOR") {
       tp2Dimension.filterAll();
    } else {
       tpIntersectFilter(tpPie.filters());
    }
    dc.redrawAll();

})
```

Comment: I realized that I need to make a slight modification to handle when the **AND** operation is selected a no filtering is being performed on timepoints.  This should be interpreted as a record must have TP-0 and TP-2 and TP-4 and TP-6 and ... instead of TP-0 or TP-2 or TP-4 or TP-6 ...  I will update my answer when implemented.

Comment: I have fixed the answer to take into account when switching to the **AND** operator but nothing is filtered for timepoints.  See the function tpIntersectFilter when filters.length === 0.

Comment: Ha! The amazing things you can do overriding the default behaviors... It's a small point, but you could make your filter function a bit simpler by just using a regular for-loop and `return false` in the loop if `indexOf` fails, `return true` if you get out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon.  I made the changes to the code based on your suggestions.