# Handling Array of objects in crossfilter data

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45487174/can-i-filter-data-based-on-an-intersection-and-in-crossfilter-dc-js) I asked about filtering data based on an intersection. With suggestions from @EthanJewett I was able to filter the timepoints by union (**OR**) or intersection (**AND**).  The data structure was:

```
let data = [
    {patientId: 101, site: "AAA", timepoints: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 18, 24]},
    {patientId: 102, site: "AAA", timepoints: [0, 2, 4, 6]},
    {patientId: 103, site: "AAA", timepoints: [8, 12, 18, 24]},
    {patientId: 104, site: "AAA", timepoints: [0, 4, 8, 18]},
    {patientId: 105, site: "AAA", timepoints: [2, 6, 12, 24]},
    {patientId: 501, site: "BBB", timepoints: [0]},
    {patientId: 502, site: "BBB", timepoints: [2]},
    {patientId: 503, site: "BBB", timepoints: [4]},
    {patientId: 504, site: "BBB", timepoints: [6]},
    {patientId: 505, site: "BBB", timepoints: [8]},
    {patientId: 506, site: "BBB", timepoints: [12]},
    {patientId: 507, site: "BBB", timepoints: [18]},
    {patientId: 508, site: "BBB", timepoints: [24]}
];
```

Continuing with this example I now have data associated with each timepoint and I am trying to chart the additional data in my dashboard while still allowing for the or/and filtering of timepoints.  Before I was given the requirement to allow an end user to filter the timepoints based on an intersection (**AND**) I would flatten the data before passing it to crossfilter, but now I am attempting to keep it unflattened.  Below is an example of the dataset with the additional data:

```
    let data = [
        {patientId: 101, site: "AAA", gender: 'Male',   timepoints: [{tp: 0, vol: 10, bool: true}, {tp: 2, vol: 15, ans: false}, {tp: 4, vol: 5, ans: true}]},
        {patientId: 201, site: "BBB", gender: 'Female', timepoints: [{tp: 0, vol: 15, ans: false}]},
        {patientId: 301, site: "CCC", gender: 'Male',   timepoints: [{tp: 4, vol: 25, ans: true}]}
    ];
```

Using the above structure I have been able to set up my crossfilter dimensions and groups and create my dc.js charts to achieve a 95% solution.  There is still one last filtering issue I am working through.  I made 4 changes to Crossfilter 1.4.0 to pass the g.key as the 5th parameter when calling reduceAdd and reduceRemove inside the iterable if block from the resetMany and updateMany functions.

**My question is**:  How do folks handle a dataset like the one above?

Like I mentioned above, previously I flattened the data before passing it to crossfilter, but with the new requirement I am attempting to keep the array of objects intake so I know that patient 101 has a timepoint at 0, 2 and 4.

I will attempt to put the current code into jsfiddle.

Comment: To add my example to jsFiddle I need to override the resetMany and updateMany functions embedded in the crossfilter function.  So can I add Crossfilter 1.4.0 as an external resource and just override the two methods in my javascript?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are trying to do. Can you do a couple of things to try to resolve this on parallel tracks: 1) Post at least your reduce functions that use the new signature so that we can see what you are using it for and 2) Explain, given your example data above what you would like to see out of a Crossfilter group based on that data. Looks like an interesting use case, and it may or may not be achievable without changes to Crossfilter itself. Thanks!

Comment: P.S. If you want to create a JSFiddle, I don't think trying to monkey-patch those methods is going to work. Easiest would probably be to post your modified Crossfilter file to Github or a Gist and then use rawgit.com to serve it into your JSFiddle.